# How can you dump contents of Clojure REPL to a file?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

So I have been working on a Clojure tutorial and it's pretty fun so far.  Unfortunately, every time I close my REPL out, I lose all of the `defn` and `def` that I created in the previous session.

So, to save time in the future, is it possible to have the Clojure REPL save everything I've typed to a file so I can dig out what I need for future uses?

Comment: In many Lisps this can be achieved by "saving an image" containing all state that has been accrued, e.g. http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Saving-a-Core-Image.html, but as far as I know Clojure does not have such a facility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think most people work by using their IDE to send fragments of code to the REPL, rather than doing a lot of direct hacking in the REPL. This way you have a better idea of the current state of the program.

Comment: sbcl have (save-and-die).

Comment: How to hot update a running web server remotely via any IDE?

Comment: @1.618 It is `save-lisp-and-die` in sbcl.

Answer (score 6):

If you [use Emacs and SLIME](http://riddell.us/ClojureSwankLeiningenWithEmacsOnLinux.html), you can save the REPL buffer to a file just like saving any other buffer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Unix-like operating system you can start your REPL using `rlwrap`. This would give you Ctrl-R for accessing commands from history in an easy way, as well as storing the history itself.

You'd just have to install `rlwrap` and prepend it to the line where you start REPL, e.g. `rlwrap lein repl`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of tips:

- I do a lot of coding in the REPL, but as soon as I write something that works then I copy/paste it into a source file. Then I can just run or reload that source file whenever I want to get a REPL environment back to a fully configured state.
- Some REPLs (e.g. the Eclipse Counterclockwise REPL that I use) keep history from previous sessions so you can up-arrow to the earlier REPL commands you want to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a harder problem than it seems because a dump like this must take into account symbol and vars dependencies and output to file in the correct order of symbols. That said since code is data one should be able to write a function that does that.